# How to write a function to detect incomplete/error process in table MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a program that I am running in main that executes a method `index_request()`

It looks like below:

```
// function to request for indexing into queue table
    public void index_request(String filepath, String status,Timestamp scheduele, Timestamp date , String errorCode) throws Exception {

        //PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(filepath));
       // java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
        String sql="insert into  test.filequeue values (default,?,?,?,?,?)";

        try{
        preparedStatement = con.connect().prepareStatement(sql);

        preparedStatement.setString(1,filepath);
        preparedStatement.setString(2,status);
        preparedStatement.setTimestamp(3,scheduele);
        preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, date);
        preparedStatement.setString(5,errorCode);

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println(" Inserted to queue table");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            preparedStatement.close();

        }

    }
```

And I want to write a separate function to detect any file in the queue table that is in Processing Status for a long period of time. 
For example the table below:

```
UniqueID   FilePath                 Status           DateTime          Error   
 1          C:\Folder1\abc.pdf       Processing    currentdatetime      Some error code if there is
 2          C:\Folder1\def.pdf       Active
```

The process should go from Active -> Processing -> Complete ,indicating the process is sucessfully to the db. In some cases, maybe there is some ongoing process that goes from Active -> Processing and it stays there for a long period of time. So I need to make a function to detect such status if it occurs for a long period of time, say an hour. And maybe keep a list of those records or display.
There is also a possibility of status go from Active -> Error for any exception occur. It should detect this issue too.

How would a function look like?

Answer (score -1):

ideal way is to throw Exception caught in Catch block, like this. And make method calling `index_request()` to handle that exception for you. 
Also executeUpdate() returns count of rows modified, if this value is 0 it means probably update/insert failed. In such cases you can throw custom Exception.

```
   catch(Exception e){
       throw e;
    }finally {
        preparedStatement.close();
    }
```

Comment: I edited my post to include more details. Hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: You need to read my edited post because it's not about catching exception now

Comment: In such case write a thread which will run in background in pre defined frequency, use select statement to identify such records and take corrective action

Comment: Yes it can be done without threads, but Threads are lightweight and best suited for such scenarios

Comment: Logic is very simple. Add a new column in table called startedAt, the moment you insert initial record(with status as Active) populate this column with systemTime. After say every 5 mins fire a select query and in where clause add condition (startedAt- currentTime)> 5 mins. This will return list of jobs which in process since last 5 mins